# python-How to delete an object in a list based on its data member

Tags: python

So i made the class below and stored instances of it in a list.

```
class Word:
    def __init__(self,word,definition,synonyms):
        self.w=word
        self.defi=definition
        self.synonyms=synonyms
```

I'm sure i can loop through the list and check every instance but i'm trying to do so using the remove method of a list. 
x is a list of Word objects

```
word="hi"
x.remove(Word if Word.w==word)
```

this gave me an error. So is there a similar way to do it?

EDIT
I was trying to simplify my question but apparently my intentions weren't clear. 
I have a dictionary whose keys are the 2 last letters of words (that users add) and whose values are lists of the words with those 2 last characters. Example:

```
w1=Word("lengthen","make something taller","some synonym")
w2=Word("woken","let someone wake up","some synonym")
w3=Word("fax","machine used for communication","some synonym")
w4=Word("wax","chemical substance","some synonym")
 ['en':(w1,w2),'ax':(w3,w4)]
```

I am trying to define a method delete which take the dictionary and a word(STRING), then it will delete the OBJECT Word containing the following word.

```
def delete(dictionary,word):
    if word[-2:] in dictionary:
        x=dictionary[word[-2:]]
        if(x.count(word)!=0):
            x.remove(Word if Word.w==word)
```

Comment: One reason `remove()`isn't working for what you trying to do is because the values in your dictionary are `tuple`s, not `list`s, and tuples don't have a `remove()` method because they're immutable. You need to either change the type of the values or replace the existing value with a new tuple object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
class Word:
    def __init__(self,word,definition,synonyms):
        self.w=word
        self.defi=definition
        self.synonyms=synonyms
    def __repr__(self):  # added to facilitate printing of tuples of Word objects
        return 'Word({}, {}, {})'.format(self.w, self.defi, self.synonyms)

w1=Word("lengthen", "make something taller", "some synonym")
w2=Word("woken", "let someone wake up", "some synonym")
w3=Word("fax", "machine used for communication", "some synonym")
w4=Word("wax", "chemical substance", "some synonym")

dictionary = {'en': (w1, w2), 'ax': (w3, w4)}

def delete(dictionary, word):
    suffix = word[-2:]
    if suffix in dictionary:
        dictionary[suffix] = tuple(word_obj for word_obj in dictionary[suffix]
                                   if word_obj.w != word)

delete(dictionary, 'woken')
print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 3):

You would generally use a list comprehension to build a new list without matches, otherwise you end up trying to modify a list while iterating over it:

```
x = [word for word in x if word.w != "hi"]
```

Note lowercase `word`; using `Word` shadows the class itself.

If altering the list in-place is crucial, you can use slicing:

```
x[:] = [word for word in x if word.w != "hi"]
```

Comment: Since `list.remove` works in-place, you may want to do `x[:] = [word for word in x if word.w != "hi"]`.  This will keep the list object the same.

Comment: @RoudyTarabay that's fine, use the `x[:]` version and it will replace the list in the dictionary.